# Add to specific line

Tags: linux, bash

I hope someone could help.

Basically I've got a config file, here is an example:

```
domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com {
    admin=false
    status=enabled
}
```

I need the command to add `, domain4.com` after domain3.com so the config will look like this:

```
domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com {
    admin=false
    status=enabled
}
```

I managed to add it to the end  but after { which is not what I want.

Comment: What did you try? Is there anything else in this file? Since I don't know the rest of this config file, I can't give you a solution that works reliably. I could say, for example, that you could replace `{` with `, domain4.com {`, or replace `domain3.com` with `domain3.com, domain4.com`, but either solution may have an unintended impact other locations in the file that contain `{` or `domain3.com`.

Comment: Good idea, thank you. `sed -i 's/ {/, domain4.com {/' config.file`

Comment: It's not clear what hte logic should be to _find_ the correct line to modify.  The modification itself is easy, but you can't just match e.g. `domain3.com`, or `{` at the end of a line, as that may occur any number of times elsewhere in the file (I'm assuming we don't see the whole file here, right?).

Comment: The command I posted above does the job, this is only a very small config for something minor, so the config you see is the whole config.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
sed "/domain3\.com/s/domain3\.com/&, domain4.com/g" filename


awk '/domain3\.com/{gsub(/domain3\.com/,"domain3.com, domain4.com",$0) }1' filename
```

output

domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com {

```
admin=false
status=enabled
```

}